# PHP Mongodb not updating array

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am not sure why but I am getting this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on a non-object in /home/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/classes/core.php on line 22
```

On that page I have this

```
public function updatemongo($from,$data)
    {
        $this->db = $m->exchange_rates;
        $collection = $this->db->exchangeDB;
        $collection->update(array("from" => $from), $data);
    }
```

this is how I am calling this function

```
foreach ($currencies as $to)
 {
    if($from != $to)
    {

        $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=l1d1t1&s='.$from.$to.'=X';
        $handle = fopen($url, 'r');

        if ($handle) {
            $result = fgetcsv($handle);
                fclose($handle);
        }

        $newdata = array('$set' => array("exchangehistory.{$result[1]}.{$result[2]}" => array("to" => $to, "rate" => $result[0], "updated" => $result[2])));
        $fetch->updatemongo($from,$newdata);

        $newdata = array('$set' => array("currentexchange" => array("to" => $to, "rate" => $result[0], "updated" => $result[2])));
        $fetch->updatemongo($from,$newdata);


    }
 }
```

and yes the file needing to access this is also has `require_once("core.php");`

Please let me know why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updatemongo()` function doesn't have access to the `$m` variable. Please pass it to the function like this:

```
$fetch->updatemongo($m, $from, $newdata);
```

And change your function definition to:

public function updatemongo($m, $from, $data)
   {

Alternatively, you can set the `m` property of the object to the connection after you've created it. For example with:

```
public function __construct)
{
    $this->m = new Mongo();
}
...
public function updatemongo($from, $data)
{
    $this->db = $this->m->exchange_rates;
    $collection = $this->db->exchangeDB;
    $collection->update(array("from" => $from), $data);
}
```

Or perhaps you can just use `$this->exchange_rates` already above... in any case, you're not making `$m` available to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo : the object "$m" is not instantiated in function `updatemongo()`

Either create it here or gain access with `global $m;` if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->exchangeDB contains null or similar when it gets placed into $collection? It's hard to tell for us since we don't know where that variable gets instantiated.

$collection->update(array("from" => $from), $data);

is the cause of your error and the error is clear: $update is not an object. otherwise it would complain "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method YourClass::yourMethod() in /my/php/file.php on line xx"